# When someone begins to do something without necessary actions / doing needed requirements

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Suppose someone comes to you and without any prior word / introduction / necessary measures wants you to make friends with them.

Or

at the beginning of a great TV program,  a TV reporter or showman without any prior word / introduction / necessary measures starts to speak.
Is there any fixed term in English for such a situation?
I'm sure there should be such a term, but I don't know what is that and how a native speaker would indicate this "doing / beginning something without.....".

Comment: Impromptu, extemporaneous, spontaneous, or unpremeditated all *kind of* work, but I think there's a better word that really fits what you're asking.  Which of course, I can't recall at the moment ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**go off half-cocked**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+off+half-cocked)
>   (figurative) *to go into action **too early or without thinking**. (Originally refers to a flintlock or matchlock gun firing prematurely, before the trigger was pulled.)*
>   Examples:
>   Don't go off half-cocked. Plan out what you're going to do.
>   Bill went off half-cocked and told everybody he was running for the state legislature.

---

[This website](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/half-cocked.html) says *We now commonly use '**go off at half-cock**' or, in America, '**go off half-cocked**', to mean '**speak or act impulsively and without proper preparation**'.* But I think that's probably written by an American who mistakenly supposes anything strange-sounding or archaic must be *British*. As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go%20off%20at%20half-cock%2Cgo%20off%20half-cocked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20off%20half%20-%20cocked%3B%2Cc0) shows, ***go off at half-cock*** never had any significant currency.

You'll also notice from that NGram that ***go off half-cock*** (no ***at***, no ***-ed***) is far from unknown. This is because in most spoken contexts it would be almost impossible for native speakers to hear that ***-ed*** anyway, so if they're not familiar with the origin they wouldn't necessarily realise it's a "past tense verb" being used adjectivally. But competent native speakers wouldn't usually get that "wrong".

Answer (score -2):

To *initiate* something would possibly describe both of the scenarios you mention. Initiate in this case meaning to cause the beginning of something, or to cause an event to begin.

Comment: But "initiate" just means "to start".  I think the OP is asking specifically about starting things without proper setup or introduction.

Comment: Yesss @stangdon . Thank you for helping me to convey the message in  my question. :)